# Example of a separately convex function which is not rank-one convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Can anyone give me an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is separately convex but not rank-one convex?
By 'separately convex' I mean convexity in each matrix entry. By 'rank-one convex' I mean convexity in any rank-one direction.
I would be totally happy with an example for $n=2$.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\mapsto ab$$
is linear in each entry, but not convex in the direction of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this example.